# using turbolinks, Responsive menu shows mobile on page load and desktop on subsequent turbolinks loads

Tags: webpack-4, turbolinks, zurb-foundation-6, ruby-on-rails-5.2

The Foundation 6 Responsive menu shows the mobile version on initial page load / refresh and is not "responsive". When Turbolinks loads the page, The proper menu appears and it is "responsive". "responsive" meaning the Javascript to change between the menus.

This is super weird because the usual Turbolinks problem is the opposite, where it works on the initial page load but not on subsequent ones. All other Foundation 6 related Javascript, like modals, work as expected no matter how the page is loaded.

I have just moved to an updated version of rails 5.2. I was on 5.2.1, webpacker 3.5, and foundation 6.5.0-rc.4. Everything worked as expected. Turbolinks has not changed versions.

I am now using Foundation 6.5.3, Rails 5.2.3, Webpack 4.34.0, Stimulus 1.1.1 ,and Turbolinks 5.2.0. No additional Gems except necessary Rails and dependencies are used. I have tried Foundation 6.5.3, 6.5.2, 6.5.1, 6.5.0, 6.5.0-rc.4, 6.4.3. None seem to revert back to normal behavior.

I have tried to reorder my Webpack application.js pack file to load modules and initialize foundation. I have tried initializing Foundation in a stimulus controller's initialize function. I have tried attaching the listener with and without Jquery. I refuse to try an inline script at the end of the html and allow unsafe-inline in my CSP. I have tried CSS solutions, no effect. I have tried messing with data-show-for attributes as well as html visibility classes but that didn't help either. I have tried adding and removing parent elements, no change. There are no errors in the browser console. Adding "ready" to the listener for "turbolinks:load" does nothing. I have looked for other Turbolinks listeners to try, but found none that made sense. I have tried to initialize it outside of and in addition to the turbolinks:load listener and it still fails, however errors show up this time in the console show foundation is initializing twice. (Tried to initialize responsive-toggle on an element that already has a Foundation plugin.)

I have included all the pertinent files to recreate this issue, unfortunately I don't have a live site to put up at the moment.

```
rails new foundationtestsite -T -d postgresql -S --webpack=stimulus --skip-listen
```

package.json (fluff removed)

```
{
  ...,
  "dependencies": {
    "@rails/webpacker": "^4.0.7",
    "actioncable": "^5.2.3",
    "activestorage": "^5.2.3",
    "foundation-sites": "^6.5.3",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "rails-ujs": "^5.2.3",
    "stimulus": "^1.1.1",
    "turbolinks": "^5.2.0",
    "webpack": "^4.34.0",
    "what-input": "^5.2.3"
  },
  ...
}
```

application.js (webpack entry / pack file)

```
import $ from 'jquery'
import jQuery from 'jquery'
import Rails from 'rails-ujs';
import Turbolinks from 'turbolinks';
import cable from 'actioncable';

// import "controllers"
import { Application } from "stimulus"
import { definitionsFromContext } from "stimulus/webpack-helpers"
const application = Application.start()
const context = require.context("controllers", true, /.js$/)

// Turbolinks
application.load(definitionsFromContext(context))
Turbolinks.start()

// images
const images = require.context('../images', true)
const imagePath = (name) => images(name, true)

// style sheets
import '../stylesheets/application.scss';

// foundation sites 6
import foundation from 'foundation-sites';
import '../javascripts/foundation_startup.js';
```

foundation_startup.js

```
import $ from 'jquery'
import jQuery from 'jquery'
import 'rails-ujs'
import 'foundation-sites'
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function(){
    $(function(){ $(document).foundation() })
});
```

html from menu partial (rendered as first element of body)

```
<div data-controller="menu" data-target="menu.menu" class="cell shrink header medium-cell-block-container">

  <div class="title-bar" data-responsive-toggle="example-animated-menu" data-hide-for="medium" data-target="menu.titleBar">
    <button class="menu-icon" type="button" data-toggle="example-animated-menu"></button>
    <div class="title-bar-title">Menu</div>
  </div>

  <div class="top-bar" id="example-animated-menu" data-target="menu.topBar">
    <div class="top-bar-left">
      <ul class="dropdown menu" data-dropdown-menu>
        <li><%= link_to "Home", root_path%></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Ever figure it out?  I'm still trying. Felt good with I got foundation to be responsive, but ran into same problem by adding a top-bar. It was responsive, but with a hamburger menu in initial load. Tried to make it sticky and it got worse. [My question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58148550/jquery-events-not-firing-using-webpacker-and-coffeescript)

Comment: I did get it to work by getting rid of turbolinks,  something I've done in the past. Foundation and turbo links don't play nice together. I get a top bar just using responsive, can't add a sticky top bar as I had working in 6.4.x